# How to create a dictionary from data

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, file-io

I am trying to create a function that creates a dictionary for each day (first column), and records the feedback of the day.

The main thing im having an issue with is how to detect that it is a new day and to create a new dictionary.

Here is the data:

```
0   21  M   34  P
0   22  F   12  N
0   28  M   67  P
1   18  M   22  P
1   21  F   88  P
1   34  F   97  N
2   55  M   21  P
2   65  M   32  P
2   33  F   55  N
2   48  F   7   P
```

​

Comment: Please show the code that you have written to try to solve this task.

Answer (score 0):

With combination of `csv.reader` + `collections.defaultdict` + `collections.Counter` objects:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
import csv
from io import StringIO

data = '''0   21  M   34  P
0   22  F   12  N
0   28  M   67  P
1   18  M   22  P
1   21  F   88  P
1   34  F   97  N
2   55  M   21  P
2   65  M   32  P
2   33  F   55  N
2   48  F   7   P'''

d = defaultdict(Counter)
reader = csv.reader(StringIO(data), skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=' ')
for row in reader:
    d[row[0]][row[4]] += 1
d = {int(k): dict(v) for k, v in d.items()}

print(d)
```

The output:

```
{0: {'P': 2, 'N': 1}, 1: {'P': 2, 'N': 1}, 2: {'P': 3, 'N': 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, without using any libraries:

```
txt = '''

0   21  M   34  P
0   22  F   12  N
0   28  M   67  P
1   18  M   22  P
1   21  F   88  P
1   34  F   97  N
2   55  M   21  P
2   65  M   32  P
2   33  F   55  N
2   48  F   7   P

'''

d = {}
for day, *_, v in (i for i in map(str.split, txt.splitlines()) if i):
    d.setdefault(day, {}).setdefault(v, 0)
    d[day][v] += 1

print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'0': {'P': 2, 'N': 1}, '1': {'P': 2, 'N': 1}, '2': {'P': 3, 'N': 1}}
```

---

To load the data from file, you can use this example:

```
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    d = {}
    for day, *_, v in (i for i in map(str.split, f_in) if i):
        d.setdefault(day, {}).setdefault(v, 0)
        d[day][v] += 1

print(d)
```